# Binary Float Data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Have this code

```
m1=[]
def decimalToBinary(num, k_prec) : 

    binary = ""   
    Integral = int(num)  
    fractional = num - Integral 
    while (Integral) :    
        rem = Integral % 2
        binary += str(rem);  

        Integral //= 2

    binary = binary[ : : -1]  

    binary += '.'

    while (k_prec) : 

        fractional *= 2
        fract_bit = int(fractional)  

        if (fract_bit == 1) : 

            fractional -= fract_bit  
            binary += '1'

        else : 
            binary += '0'

        k_prec -= 1

    return binary  

if __name__ == "__main__" : 
    xr=([0.3,0.4,0.5])
    for i in xr:
        n = xr
        k = 32
        a=(decimalToBinary(n[i], k)) 
        m1.append(a)
```

The problem is that that i have a list/data which i wanted to convert in binary but by running this code i got this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 59, in 
>       print(decimalToBinary(n[i], k))
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
>   Plus i want the binary converted data in an array .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted far too much code: the function is unnecessary, as the error is in the argument formation.  Look at this:

```
xr=([0.3,0.4,0.5])
for i in xr: 
    n = xr
    print("n =", n, "\ti =", i)
    print(n[i])
```

Error:

```
n = [0.3, 0.4, 0.5]     i = 0.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(n[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

As the error message tells you, the problem is in the list index.
You used a float, which is illegal.  I suspect that what you want is simply

```
a = decimalToBinary(i, k)
```